# Lifetime scope for Autofac components in MVC 5, SignlaR and quartz

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, autofac

I am trying to register components and dependencies with Autofac in a MVC 5 application that also uses the following:

Application Services
   SignalR 
   Quartz.NET

The MVC container I register in startup.cs class with:

```
var resolver = new Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver( container );
DependencyResolver.SetResolver( resolver );
```

and for signalR:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
```

But don't know about how to configure/register/resolve for Quartz.

Even I tried with this way:- https://github.com/alphacloud/Autofac.Extras.Quartz.

But getting below error:----

> The request lifetime scope cannot be created because the HttpContext is not available.

Can anyone please help me to out this problem.